# How to set selected an option in multiple mat-select option in angular7

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I have array of selected locations and all_locations.I want to set selected in mat-select option if that location appears in selected locations.

```
Users_loc=[username:'A1',
    locations:{'A','B','C'}
]

all_loc=[location_name:'A',
        location_name:'B',
        location_name:'C',
        location_name:'D',
        location_name:'E',
        location_name:'F',...,
        location_name:'Y',
        location_name:'Z']

<div class="form-controls">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select mulitple (selectionChange)="regionSelectionChange($event.value)" placeholder="Region">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regions" [value]="region.location_name">{{region.location_name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I want check mark in front of A,B,C in mat-select ..

Comment: Users_loc.locations is array or object

Comment: Is it multiselect? Then "multiple" attribute should be there.

Comment: yes its multiselect.I get data from server for users_loc and all_loc.

Comment: Ok. Then check the below answer and whether it is working or not. If it works then mark it as correct. It will be helpful for others also.

Comment: @Tushar I will check

Answer (score 0):

On selection, if you are getting data like this : [A,B,C] then you can pass this type of array with [(ngModel)] like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="regionSelectionChange($event.value)" placeholder="Region" multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedData">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regions" [value]="region.location_name">{{region.location_name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In TS :

```
selectedData = [A,B,C]
```